# Black Hole Power Plant

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-worlds

I had this idea for my sci-fi book, there's not going to be a **central** galactic government, very contested little time, but I do wanna pursue this.

The more shadowy inhabitants of the center of our galaxy are not from here. They have traveled through dimensional doorways opened by the extreme forces around the supermassive black holes at galactic centers, located within the holes themselves. I'm not sure precisely where they're from, or if they even know, but their capital, here, is centered around Sagittarius A.

I'm just not sure on the laws of physics, the current idea I have is a metal planet like sphere separated under habitable domes to counter incoming radiation, while the inner layers filled with secrets and experiments.

My question is what would be the most efficient way to draw power from a black hole's excess, should it even be a city or just a scattered array of stations and panels?

Comment: Check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20813/how-would-a-black-hole-power-plant-work.

Comment: One very important thing you need to know when talking about power is that what drives the cosmos, and everything in it, is not energy itself (the universe has exactly the same amount of energy in it now as it did at the big bang), but rather the flow of energy from "high density" to "low density" locations. So it is not enough just to ask "where does the energy come from" but also "where is it going". If you set up a system with high energy input, but poor energy output, everyone in that system would fry.

Answer (score 12):

A black hole, if it has an accretion disk, will cause said disk to radiate X rays, due to the dissipation of the momentum carried by the matter falling in it.

Just harvest those X rays and convert them to usable energy, more or less like we do with our solar panels.

Comment: That's the idea, I think having it sphere-shaped will help the plant speed up energy consumption for being the size Sagittarius is.

Comment: @KradSaxon A complete sphere around a massive object is not stable. And I think you might be underestimating the size of the event horizon and thus the also the radius at which it's possible to have a stable orbit of Sagittarius A*.

Comment: If you're harvesting radiation from the accretion disk to create power, you may as well harvest the immense heat from it as well - which can then be used to spin turbines, as is done with nuclear power.

Comment: While this X-ray radiation can contain lots and lots of energy, it's also quite unstable, and the bursts will tend to fry anything in the vicinity. If I were an alien that came out of a supermassive black hole, I'd try to run away as fast as possible. Especially if I didn't collect prior intelligence on what masses are orbiting that black hole how closely.

Comment: If I were an alien that could emerge from a black hole I don't think x-rays would bother me too much.

Answer (score 8):

**One wave of the hands.**

Your people traveled through dimensional doorways that you invented for the story.  Since the transdimensional 
doorways 
 are already invented (and no-one can complain about their physics!)
, use those.  Stuff from that original dimension continues to stream through them in energetic, coruscating streams.  It is not great for our dimension that all this weird stuff comes busting in and getting mixed up with the native stuff and in fact discovery of that stuff might be the first clue for our dimension that something is up.

Your invader people are made of weird stuff like that, and they make use of the streams using
 devices like great waterwheels or wind turbines, being turned by the difference in dimensional energies and the creepy stuff that those
energies are propelling into our dimension.

Comment: That's a great idea. The structure around the hole could be more of a waystation into the Milky Way. The doors will be shut for the most part as they are looking for a specific place, I was going to use repulsive gravity as a solution for FTL, having wind turbines for engines sounds neat, and true there are probably more powerful sources of energy in extra dimensions if they exist. If you're interested they're called Munraas, and I had the idea of them being bipeds with a glimmering foggy headplate with changing colors of energy where their brain would be. Lots of gratitude.

Answer (score 7):

[**The Penrose Process**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process)

This is a way to extract energy from a spinning black hole. It is similar to the classic sci-fi trope where you slingshot a spacecraft around a rotating body. In both cases you launch something near a heavy rotating body so that what emerges afterwards has greater energy that what went in, and the body is rotating slightly slower.

You carefully line up two asteroids and drop them into the black hole. One is swallowed up and the second comes flying out with greater energy than before. Then you somehow catch that asteroid and harvest the kinetic energy. There is no need to build a superstructure around the black hole.

Comment: To build on this, you can actually target a laser just outside a rotating black hole's event horizon in such a manner that it curves around and comes directly back at you.  Correctly done, the laser will have been blue shifted, and thus have more energy than was used to originally fire it.  Set up collectors to absorb the incoming energy and repeat.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: Is this the same as doing the asteroid thing but instead of a few big particles you use a stream of little ones?

Comment: Actually, I may be misremembering a bit from an Issac Arthur video.   You may have to be moving towards the black hole at significant speeds for this to result in an energy gain.  The video was in the context of using lasers as propulsion and using rotating black holes as waypoints, which would essentially power your trip almost entirely off the rotational inertia of black holes.

Answer (score 4):

Kurzgesagt has a nice [video](https://youtu.be/ulCdoCfw-bY) about black holes in which they introduce 2 methods to harvest energy from a black hole. One is the Penrose process as mentioned in a [previous answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/176805/56150) (you drop a thing into the black hole while going around it for a boost) and the other is building a mirror array around the hole and shooting EM waves through a hole in the array (the surviving waves would accelerate and can be caught in another hole in the array).

Answer (score 2):

Sagittarius A is orbited by a number of stars. [Here is the current list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*#Orbiting_stars). Most of them are way more massive than the Sun, and thus give off more energy.

You could harvest a lot of energy from the star system with regular solar panels, or multiple Dyson spheres. You can then beam the energy to the base planet.

Removing energy from the black hole directly would reduce its mass and thus change the planet's orbit.

Comment: I'll do some research on that.

Comment: There's a lot of mass in a black hole. A civilization could use it for billions of years before noticing a meaningful change, assuming they don't keep feeding it more mass to replace what they harvest as energy.

Comment: @Harabeck feeding mass into a black hole to make up for the lost mass due to energy extraction means you are losing more energy than you are gaining overall.

Comment: @Renan doing that would be a means of storing the energy.

Comment: @Harabeck in lay terms, it would be like recharging your cell phone. You can only do it so many times, and after a few months you notice a full charge lasts less and less. You cannot beat the second law of thermodynamics. If you magically could, you probably wouldn't bother about extracting energy from a black hole.

Comment: @Renan A better analogy would be like adding fuel to a fire. A piece of wood releases more energy as it burns than I spent picking it up. Now the Universe as a whole spent more energy that I get out to make the wood in the first place, but that doesn't mean that thermodynamics prevents me from cooking my meal.

Comment: @Harabeck the proper analogy here is a solar panel and a laser, both powering each other up.

Comment: @Renan It's not. I don't have create mass from nothing to feed to the black hole. Are you assuming Penrose process only?

Comment: @Harabeck no, but I'm calculating budgets. You have to move the mass all the way past the event horizon and there is a ΔV involved. Also if you are throwing mass to keep the black hole in a certain size, you are feeding it as much energy as you're getting at the very least, but no proces is 100% efficient. Finally if you have technology to extract energy from a black hole, you could probably save a lot of energy by turning a piece of mass into energy some other way and not having to move the mass into the black hole.

Comment: "you are feeding it as much energy as you're getting at the very least" I guess I don't see how that's true. The kinetic energy of the object being fed to the black hole should be a fraction of what you get out as hawking radiation, just like the energy I get from a piece of burning wood has nothing to do with how hard I through it into the fire. The energy conversion process is separate.

Comment: @Harabeck a black hole's mass and size are proportional to how much energy it has. If you are keeping it a fixed size, you are keeping it at a constant energy level.

Comment: But I didn't spend energy to create the mass I'm feeding to the black hole. What you're saying only makes sense from a universal frame of reference. The Universe as a whole is moving toward entropy, it doesn't gain energy when you throw stuff at the black hole. But that's true of any kind of generator.

Comment: @Harabeck I see your point now.

Answer (score 1):

To maximize the energy output of a black hole, you want it to be relatively small as the smaller it is the more hawking radiation it outputs. But you also have to keep feeding it matter so it doesn't completely evaporate.

I suggest you look into the idea of Kugelblitz drives for starships, as you you'll likely find answers to a lot of the questions you have about using black holes for power.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_starship

Comment: You'll get less energy from the black hole than the energy you spend putting things in it, if you do it this way.

Comment: @Renan Right, like how we lose energy as we mine coal. Wait a minute...

Comment: @Harabeck throwing mass at a black hole as a means of energy storage is like making your own coal and burying it to dig it up and burn it later. Your net gain is negative. Mining coal nowadays gives us energy because we ourselves did not invest energy into making the coal in the first place.

Comment: @RenanI think you need to read more about the Kugelblitz drive concept. If I lightly toss a rock at a black hole, the energy I get out as Hawking radiation is far more than I spent gently tossing the rock.

Comment: Black holes, convert 100% of mass to energy.
Burning coal releases the chemical energy, which is a tiny percentage of mass energy.
Black hole plants may be the most efficient method of creating energy.

Answer (score 0):

you could create matter out of nothing near a black hole, you just need to wait till spontaneous creation of a particle/antiparticle pair and for one of them to be sucked into the black hole. Boom you have a free particle. multiply times gazillion, profit!